# Is there any way to keep track of events emitted by the deployed child contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, registries

Is there anyway to keep track of the events emitted by the child contracts ( ie contracts deployed inside another contract (parent ) ). I know we could use the indexer to get the events emitted by a single contract. But how do I keep track of say multiple child contracts ( say 1000 or even 100000). Any solution or suggestion in the direction of solution would help.

I tried the Listener method using ethers.js. But even that makes no sense as we cannot keep deploying listeners for every contract that is being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a decentralized event listener - https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/events/EventEmitter.sol

Answer (score 0):

the way it is implemented is that the Parent contract must emit an event called something like "ChildCreated" including the address of the child. Then you listen for an event called something like "ChildEmitsSomething" and identify every child using its address (which is already known since the emission of the event from the parent) , the address is part of `log` structure when you read the event.
Check out how Uniswap V3 works, it tracks all the children contracts and there are a lot of them